# Time complexity of java code

Tags: java, algorithm, for-loop, time, big-o

**Questions**

1) Why is the code fragment below said to be O(log n) (by class lecturer)?

2) Why does the for loop not terminate immediately when n>0?
edit: Answered below- j always > 0 so infinite (theoretically) loop or until overflow (in practise)

**Background**
I am doing a course and tonight we had a session on time complexity of algorithms.  It is taught with Java.
For all the other code frags, I understood the complexity, but this one confuses me completely.

```
public class SampleClassOnly {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
     int n = 100;
     for(int j = n; j > 0; j++){
     System.out.println(j);
     }
   }
}
```

Now, I've run the code to test it, and for n<=0, I can see it has complexity of O(1) as there are 5 steps executed.  For n>0 it seems to run over 1000 times (I used a visualiser to check this visually- see below)

I also find it confusing that it does not stop when the termination condition is met, i.e. j>0 (highlighted below).

[image: Code being run in Visualiser]

Perhaps I am missing something obvious?  Appreciate any pointers. Thanks.

Comment: Whomever said that's O(log n) is very wrong. Why do you think the loop should terminate immediately? A for-loop stops when the condition is **false** (not when it's true).

Comment: The loop will run while the condition is true. Your loop is infinite when n > 0.

Comment: `j > 0` is not the termination condition but the opposite of the termination condition: the loop _continues_ while `j > 0` is true.

Comment: @marstran It's not infinite. It loops until `j` overflows.

Comment: Firstly, learn programming or Java.

Comment: First of all, the condition is never met as you are increment the value of j ,when initialized to a positive number, till it is greater than 0 (which it always be). So its gonna run for ever (ideally).

Comment: It's O(1). It has a fixed execution time of 2^31-100 iterations (it stops when `j` overflows which is a negative number that will cause the `for` loop to terminate)

Comment: So it could not be O(log n)- that's what I thought. I asked for clarification, and got a link to read, and another example to look at, but in the example I could "see" it was O(log n) but that code had me stumped.  If it was j-- then instead, the complexity would be O(n), yes?

Comment: Incorrect. It will definitely terminate.

Comment: Only when j overflows...

Comment: @shmosel Yeah, that's true ;)

Comment: Ok, so the lecturer made a mistake, I'm not mad, and I muddled the termination cond.  Apologies, I code in Python and find Java awkward.  Should I delete the question or leave it?  Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that this question is downvote-worthy. Obviously, the premise of the question as originally formulated ended up being incorrect, but that doesn't mean that the question isn't useful; I upvoted because I think that the premises were incorrect for an interesting/instructive reason.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely **not** O(log n). This is O(n) because the number of operations will vary linearly with whatever you set `n` to (assuming, of course, that we treat `n` as an input that we could in principle change). (There is, of course, a hard limit to the number of "steps" that the loop could take, which is `2^31` steps). (Also, important point: this'll perform a constant number of operations for *any particular* value of `n`, which is why @Bohemian argued in the comments for this being O(1)).

As other people have pointed out, the loop invariant can't possibly be false (assuming that you set `n` to a positive number); the only reason that it'll halt at all is that you'll eventually get an integer overflow.

> For n>0 it seems to run over 1000 times

Yes, it'll run `2^31-n` times and then overflow, so for most values of `n` it'll run *much* more than 1000 times.

Answer (score 1):

Note that your for-loop:

```
for (int j = n; j > 0; j++)
{
    /* code in block */
}
```

is functionally equivalent to:

```
{
    int j = n;
    while (j > 0)
    {
        {
            /* code in block */
        }
        j++;
    } 
}
```

So, as others already said, it will run until j overflows. And since it is linearly dependent on n, it is O(n).

I guess you wanted to do:

```
for (int j = n; j > 0; j--)
```

then it will run n times, with j going down from n to 1. But even then, it is O(n).

Answer (score 0):

It's O(1). Not O(log n). Not O(n).

It has essentially constant time, because the maximum number of iterations for any value of `n` is 2<sup>31</sup> (when `n = 0`).

Being capped, the time complexity is "constant".